# How to get the accuracy score through the meanshift algorithm?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to get the accuracy score for meanshift based on the code below.

I tried with a classification algorithm from sklearn and the "score" was able to produce the accuracy, but when it comes to clustering algorithm such as Birch, kmeans, meanshift, algglomerative, it seems like I'm not able to get the accuracy score through the same code.

```py
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift
kfold = 5

mean = MeanShift()
Count1 = 1
Aa1 = 0

Cnt1 = len(X)
kf = KFold(n_splits=kfold)
            
for train_index,test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train,X_test = X[train_index],X[test_index]
    Y_train,Y_test = Y[train_index],Y[test_index]
    
    model1 = mean
    model1.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    Pa_1=model1.predict(X_test)
    AC1=model1.score(X_test,Y_test)
    
    Aa1 += AC1
       
print()
print("Accuracy for DT GA: %f" % (Aa1/kfold))
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError
  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_33368/2687219843.py in <module>
     12     model1.fit(X_train, Y_train)
     13     Pa_1=model1.predict(X_test)
---> 14     AC1=model1.score(X_test,Y_test)
     15 
     16     Aa1 += AC1

AttributeError: 'MeanShift' object has no attribute 'score'
```

Comment: Why are you expecting `sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.score()` to exist? The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html) does not make any reference of it.

Comment: ya, i read through does not have the .score output. May i know how to see the accuracy through meanshift algorithm?

Comment: Okay, I updated the title to make that question more clear. The attribute error in general is already asked and answered many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the error is true. `MeanShift` really doesn't have any `score` attribute.
As you wamted to get the accuracy, you need to use `matrics` from `sklearn`.

I am giving you a small snippet.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

...
...

Pa_1=model1.predict(X_test)
AC1=accuracy_score(Y_test, Pa_1)    #<--- See this line
...
```

See the `accuracy_score` documentation:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html

You can check more matrices as per your need: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics